# Atomically write 64kB

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I need to write something like 64 kB of data atomically in the middle of an existing file. That is all, or nothing should be written. How to achieve that in Linux/C?

Comment: When you say 'write in the middle of an existing file', do you mean 'overwrite a block of data in the middle of a file' or 'insert new data at a specific position and move the rest of the data in the file'?  They're two very different operations; you can do the first in a single `write()` system call, but the second is much trickier and cannot be done atomically.

Comment: @Jonathan Overwrite. One `write` is absolutely NOT atomic.

Comment: @Tibor Overwrite. Please, read my comments carefully. Thank you.

Comment: @James Yeah, sorry, I didn't see that.

Comment: upload the file into an SQL-DB with transaction logging turned on, insert the 64K block of data and then unload the file.

Comment: I said what I said so you can quickly solve your problem because you won't be able to do it in C/Linux unless you write several functions to mimic how DB's commit and rollback writes.

Comment: Perhaps you could do the write(), then read it back to verify it complted, if not, then restore copy of original file?

Comment: @FrankComputer write/read solution need not to work because of the page cache in Linux.

Comment: So then sync, or create a raw disk partition for your file and manage the I/O yourself.

Comment: Why would it not be atomic?  Once a file has been opened for reading or writing, that process owns it, and other processes can't read/write it.  Obviously, *your* code must be atomic (that is, if you have multiple threads, you need to be careful, just as you always should).  The only time I can think it wouldn't be atomic is certain exploits that attack a running program right as it's opening a file--but those are exceptional cases.

Comment: @IanMallet, it does not work that way in Linux, Mac OS (X or classic), or other Unix-like operating systems. Any number of processes can open a file simultaneously. Also, file locks in these operating systems are advisory, not mandatory. Windows behaves differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, or at least there's not any interface that guarantees as part of its contract that the write would be atomic. In other words, if there is a way that's atomic right now, that's an implementation detail, and it's not safe to rely on it remaining that way. You probably need to find another solution to your problem.

If however you only have one writing process, and your goal is that other processes either see the full write or no write at all, you can just make the changes in a temporary copy of the file and then use `rename` to atomically replace it. Any reader that already had a file descriptor open to the old file will see the old contents; any reader opening it newly by name will see the new contents. Partial updates will never be seen by any reader.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few approaches to modify file contents "atomically". While technically the modification itself is never truly atomic, there are ways to make it *seem* atomic to all other processes.

1. My favourite method in Linux is to take a *write lease* using [`fcntl(fd, F_SETLEASE, F_WRLCK)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fcntl.2.html). It will only succeed if `fd` is the only open descriptor to the file; that is, nobody else (not even this process) has the file open. Also, the file must be owned by the user running the process, or the process must run as root, or the process must have the `CAP_LEASE` capability, for the kernel to grant the lease.

   When successful, the lease owner process gets a signal (`SIGIO` by default) whenever another process is opening or truncating the file. The opener will be blocked by the kernel for up to `/proc/sys/fs/lease-break-time` seconds (45 by default), or until the lease owner releases or downgrades the lease or closes the file, whichever is shorter. Thus, the lease owner has dozens of seconds to complete the "atomic" operation, without any other process being able to see the file contents.

   There are a couple of wrinkles one needs to be aware of. One is the privileges or ownership required for the kernel to allow the lease. Another is the fact that the other party opening or truncating the file will only be delayed; the lease owner cannot replace (hardlink or rename) the file. (Well, it can, but the opener will always open the *original* file.) Also, renaming, hardlinking, and unlinking/deleting the file does not affect the file contents, and therefore are not affected at all by file leases.

   Remember also that you need to handle the signal generated. You can use `fcntl(fd, F_SETSIG, signum)` to change the signal. I personally use a trivial signal handler -- one with an empty body -- to catch the signal, but there are other ways too.
2. A portable method to achieve *semi-atomicity* is to use a memory map using [`mmap()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html). The idea is to use `memmove()` or similar to replace the contents as quickly as possible, then use [`msync()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/msync.2.html) to flush the changes to the actual storage medium.

   If the memory map offset in the file is a multiple of the page size, the mapped pages reflect the page cache. That is, any other process reading the file, in any way -- `mmap()` or `read()` or their derivatives -- will immediately see the changes made by the `memmove()`. The `msync()` is only needed to make sure the changes are also stored on disk, in case of a system crash -- it is basically equivalent to `fsync()`.

   To avoid preemption (kernel interrupting the action due to the current timeslice being up) and page faults, I'd first read the mapped data to make sure the pages are in memory, and then call `sched_yield()`, before the `memmove()`. Reading the mapped data should fault the pages into page cache, and `sched_yield()` releases the rest of the timeslice, making it extremely likely that the `memmove()` is not interrupted by the kernel in any way. (If you do not make sure the pages are already faulted in, the kernel will likely interrupt the `memmove()` for each page separately. You won't see that in the process, but other processes see the modifications to occur in page-sized chunks.)

   This is not exactly atomic, but it is practical: it does not give you any guarantees, only makes the race window very very short; therefore I call this *semi-atomic*.

   Note that this method is compatible with file leases. One could *try* to take a write lease on the file, but fall back to leaseless memory mapping if the lease is not granted within some acceptable time period, say a second or two. I'd use [`timer_create()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) and [`timer_settime()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_settime.2.html) to create the timeout timer, and the same empty-body signal handler to catch the `SIGALRM` signal; that way the `fcntl()` is interrupted (returns `-1` with `errno == EINTR`) when the timeout occurs -- with the timer interval set to some small value (say 25000000 nanoseconds, or 0.025 seconds) so it repeats very often after that, interrupting syscalls if the initial interrupt is missed for any reason.
3. Most userspace applications create a copy of the original file, modify the contents of the copy, then replace the original file with the copy.

   Each process that opens the file will only see complete changes, never a mix of old and new contents. However, anyone keeping the file open, will only see their original contents, and not be aware of any changes (unless they check themselves). Most text editors do check, but daemons and other processes do not bother.

   Remember that in Linux, the file name and its contents are two separate things. You can open a file, unlink/remove it, and still keep reading and modifying the contents for as long as you have the file open.

There are other approaches, too. I do not want to suggest any specific approach, because the optimal one depends heavily on the circumstances: Do the other processes keep the file open, or do they always (re)open it before reading the contents? Is atomicity preferred or absolutely required? Is the data plain text, structured like XML, or binary?

EDITED TO ADD:

Please note that there are no ways to guarantee beforehand that the file will be successfully modified atomically. Not in theory, and not in practice.

You might encounter a write error with the disk full, for example. Or the drive might hiccup at just the wrong moment. I'm only listing three **practical** ways to make it **seem** atomic in typical use cases.

The reason write leases are my favourite is that I can always use `fcntl(fd,F_GETLEASE,&ptr)` to check whether the lease is still valid or not. If not, then the write was not atomic.

High system load is unlikely to cause the lease to be broken for a 64k write, if the same data has been read just prior (so that it will likely be in page cache). If the process has superuser privileges, you can use `setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS,getpid(),-20)` to temporarily raise the process priority to maximum while taking the file lease and modifying the file. If the data to be overwritten has just been read, it is extremely unlikely to be moved to swap; thus swapping should not occur, either.

In other words, while it is quite possible for the lease method to fail, in practice it is almost always successful -- even without the extra tricks mentioned in this addendum.

Personally, I simply check if the modification was not atomic, using the `fcntl()` call after the modification, prior to `msync()`/`fsync()` (making sure the data hits the disk in case a power outage occurs); that gives me an absolutely reliable, trivial method to check whether the modification was atomic or not.

For configuration files and other sensitive data, I too recommend the rename method. (Actually, I prefer the hardlink approach used for NFS-safe file locking, which amounts to the same thing but uses a temporary name to detect naming races.) However, it has the problem that any process keeping the file open will have to check and reopen the file, voluntarily, to see the changed contents.

Comment: Neither locking the file, nor using mmap guarantees atomicity in the event of a power failure half way through the write - which was presumably what the OP wanted.

Comment: Method 2 is definitely wrong. `msync` is a **NO-OP** with regards to the logical contents of the file which other programs see. Its only affect is to help protect the physical integrity of data on disk in the event of a power failure. Haven't read the other options in enough detail yet to comment on whether they're correct.

Comment: To better explain the `mmap` issue, if your process gets descheduled (preempted) in the middle of performing its write to the mapped region, other processes will see (whether they use `mmap` or `read` to read it) the partially-written data. And that's just on uni-proc. On SMP, it's much worse.

Comment: As for method 1, it's vulnerable to failure under (potentially *intentionally* generated) high system load, especially if you have swap enabled. In a worst case (depending on the consequences of other apps seeing only partial updates), this could result in privilege elevation. "Atomic unless a timeout expires" is not atomic.

Comment: @MarkR: Power failure during a file modification, prior a `fsync()` or `msync()`, *always* leads to uncertain file contents.

Comment: @R..: First, I did explain that `msync()` is only used to make sure the data hits the disk (in case of power failure); it is not used for any kind of atomicity guarantee. The mapping matches the page cache if the offset is page aligned.

Comment: @R..: Second, if you use `MAP_NORESERVE` for the `mmap()`, swap does not come into play at all. Note that the lease only needs to be taken for the `memmove()` call (or `write()` if not using a memory map); the contents should already be in page cache, having read once already. The `sched_yield()` further ensures the `memmove()` is not interrupted.

Like I said, the approaches do not *guarantee* atomicity. Even hard link rename is not guaranteed atomic against sudden power loss.

Comment: `MAP_NORESERVE` is a no-op. `rename` does guarantee atomicity on a running system. On a system with hardware failure of course there can be no guarantees of anything.

Comment: The only, and easiest way you can guarantee atomicity is to do this within a DB transaction with commit and rollback capability, period!

Answer (score 3):

Disk writes cannot be atomic without a layer of abstraction. You should keep a journal and revert if a write is interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know a write below the size of PIPE_BUF is atomic. However I never rely on this. If the programs that access the file are written by you, you can use [flock()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) to achieve exclusive access. This system call sets a lock on the file and allows other processes that know about the lock to get access or not.

Comment: `PIPE_BUF` has nothing whatsoever to do with regular files. It only applies to pipes.

Comment: I know! (it's obvious, given the name of the macro **PIPE_BUF**) :-) That was a general comment. The solution I'm actually giving is file locking!